Dynamic Run-name based on environment variable set in script
For my multiple scheduled job, I want to set run-name dynamically based on job action/output
I have 4 scheduled jobs which run on Desktop, Iphone Browser, API Test and Android Browser. Based on scheduled time, I want to set the run-name differently for each run.
I tried setting it with environment variable but didn't get success..
Code Snippet :
name: GitHub Workflow Scheduled Test
run-name: Regression Test on ${{github.env.runName}}
on:
workflow_dispatch:
schedule:
- cron: '20 10 * * *' #Desktop Run
- cron: '25 10 * * *' #Iphone Run
- cron: '30 10 * * *' #API run
- cron: '35 10 * * *' #Android run
jobs:
test:
name: Scheduled Job
timeout-minutes: 240
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Set Run Name
uses: dkershner6/switch-case-action@v1
id: setRunName
with:
default: QA - Desktop
conditionals-with-values: |
${{github.event.schedule=='20 10 * * *'}} => QA - Desktop
${{github.event.schedule=='25 10 * * *'}} => QA - Iphone
${{github.event.schedule=='30 10 * * *'}} => QA - API
${{github.event.schedule=='35 10 * * *'}} => QA - Android
- run: |
echo runName=${{steps.setRunName.outputs.value}} >> $GITHUB_ENV

I want run-name: Regression Test on ${{github.env.runName}} code to print like Regression Test on QA - Desktop based on the output.
Currently it is printing blank :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/ZNSEX.png
Expected Response like :
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/lyDri.png
Looking forward for better approch.. Thanks in advance.

It won't work that way, as you are setting the variable after it will be used by GitHub. The runName variable is set during the workflow run execution (in a job step), whereas the run-name field is used to start the workflow run and display the workflow run name on the GitHub UI (before the job execution start).

Yeah.. That's what the problem statement is.. I want to set different name in run-name for each scheduled job...

As this field can't be dynamically set that way, you won't be able to achieve what you want without creating a different workflow file for each cron trigger (with an hardcoded run-name in the configuration)

Did you try using a if/else expression in the run-name field? Something like: run-name: ${{ github.event.schedule != '20 10 * * * && 'QA - Desktop' || 'QA - other option'  }} ? It's a workaround that won't resolve the whole issue, but it could allow you to at least create 2 workflows instead of 4.

I wanted to share this workflow if anyone is looking to have a dynamic environment name in the run-name.
As of 25-Dec-2025, I can confirm that this is working for me. Although the doc says that the run-name has only access to {{ inputs }} and {{ github }} contexts, but when I added a variable at the repository level (under Github secrets) and accessed it using the vars.DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT surprisingly it worked. You may use the same trick to achieve what you are looking for.
May be this is an undocumented feature ( bit reluctant to post if they remove it after its discovery  ).
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'abcd/**'
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: 'Choose the deployment environment'
        required: false
        default: 'DEV'
        type: choice
        options:
          - DEV
          - UAT
          - PROD

run-name: '${{ github.event.inputs.environment || vars.DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT }} - Run ID: ${{ github.run_id }} - by @${{ github.actor }}'

